# Pairing bluetooth device with user defined PIN QT

Tags: qt, bluetooth, pairing

Qt says in its documentation the pin is automatically defined, but I needed it to be '0000' because of the devices I want to pair with. The same question was already answered here before in SO, problem is the url that kept the code to the answer was broken and I couldn't get in touch with the person who answered.

Comment: `0000` is the default PIN for most devices. Have you tried setting / using  `QBluetoothLocalDevice::AuthorizedPaired` instead of `QBluetoothLocalDevice::Paired`?

Comment: Ya, I did, didn't work out :( because the pin is called when the pairing returns an error, which is specific for some Bluetooth adapters